# Why isn't my Sense HAT working on a Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: pi-3

It was my birthday yesterday and I got a sense hat for my birthday from a brother. I opened it up and stuck it on to the GPIO pins (I think that's what they are called) and I looked up a tutorial on how to get it to work. I noticed on the back of the packaging it says compatible with Pi 2B, Pi B+ and Pi A+..

When I turned it on and I had it screwed down to the Pi 3, it flashes all of its lights really bright and a red light turns on on the Pi 3. Then, it doesn't do anything.

The tutorial said to get the latest version of Raspbian.. and I updated it with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

I have no idea what `dist` means but that's what I did anyway.. when it finished (it took ages) the sense hat didn't respond when I put in Python:

```
from sense_hat import SenseHat
sense = SenseHat()
```

The  sense_hat didn't come up in red like the pi's website said it would.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: i think that you need a lot more code than that to make it work.

Comment: `The sense_hat didn't come up in red like the pi's website said it would.` ... please post a link to that web page

Comment: i have the support for it. it turnes out the sense hat is busted.                                         edit: i have tried many methods, and i have contacted rpi support and waiting for them to respond.

Comment: glad that you were able to figure it out yourself